# How to know if new row was inserted, or if extant row was updated?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

When using `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` in MySQL (with PDO), **how can one check if an extant row was updated, or in a new row was inserted**? I'm using PHP's PDO with a prepared query to insert:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO some_table (f_name, l_name) ";
$sql.= "VALUES (:f_name, :l_name) ";
$sql.= "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ";
$sql.= "    f_name = VALUES(f_name) ";
$sql.= "    l_name = VALUES(l_name) ";

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(':f_name', 'Jeff');
$stmt->bindValue(':l_name', 'Atwood');
$stmt->execute();
```

Now I would like to output `Updated!` or `Added!` as appropriate. How can I check this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check by checking number of affected rows.

Whenever a row is inserted it returns exactly same number as number of inserted rows. However, when it update, It multiply by 2 and return as affected rows.

For example,

If you are adding two row, and
Row is create: affected row would be 2
Row is updated: affected row would be 4

Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Also, to check number of affected rows you can use rowCount function ( https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php )